# Insert and Update in Single Table using Merge?

Tags: oracle, merge

I want to Update or insert Oracle Table based on condition.

Consider that in the table have 2 columns (like id and name), one or more name having the same id. In this situation i want to check the id and name (like 1,'Buyer'), if its exist then i want to update name 'Buyer' to 'Service Provider'. otherwise i want to just insert the values (1,'Service Provider').

I tried this through Merge, but it's update all the name column of id 1 to 'Service Provider'.

```
merge into party_type p
using (select 1 party_id, 'Buyer' party_type from dual) t
  on (t.party_id = p.party_id)
when matched then
  update set party_type = 'Service Provider'
when not matched then
  insert (party_id,party_type) values(1,'Service Provider');
```

Available data in the table:

```
1  Buyer
1  Buyer Agent
1  Vendor
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you need to join on both columns

```
merge into party_type p
using (select 1 party_id, 'Buyer' party_type from dual) t
  on (t.party_id = p.party_id and t.party_type = p.party_type)
when matched then
  update set party_type = 'Service Provider'
when not matched then
  insert (party_id,party_type) values(1,'Service Provider');
```

Comment: I tried this, but i got error, after that only i make this question in Stackoverflow.

Comment: The error is Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "P"."PARTY_TYPE". Is there any easy way to do this.